# Python, How to check windows application progress

Tags: python, windows

In python, is there any way to check the progress of another windows application. That is to say for example, downloading a file in chrome, or converting a file in handbrake, Is there any way to get the current status of these processes. Specifically I want my script to wait until another program finishes a conversion, then continue.

Comment: There is no general way to do so. If you specify the application you want to use though, there might be a solution. Some applications provide scripting functionality or command line , such as Blender, Gimp or calibre. If you are talking about Handbrake, it has a [CLI](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/CLIGuide)  that you can access.

Comment: I'm actually using a program called freemake converter just because it allows you to join files while converting which is something I need. I had no idea Handbrake had a CLI, that'll definitely come in handy in the future so thanks. I didn't have much hope but I saw all these programs displaying their progress on their icon in the taskbar so I hoped maybe these  programs all sent that information in a specific way to make use of this feature and so maybe it would readable! no such luck yet finding anything yet though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess a work-around for this would be to check the process's memory usage with shell command.
If the specific process does not matter, I guess you could run a shell command and get the general system memory status. But this will only work for memory hungry processes.

Comment: This is such a great idea! especially for video conversion softwares which are always so memory hungry, I'll give this a try thanks!

Comment: Cool. Please upvote if it works for you. I think video conversions will be such an obvious spike in your memory usage that it will be easy to spot. Just be sure that you establish what your baseline memory load is. You don't want your code to stall while listen to music or something like that.

Comment: Yes that's true and I'll definitely upvote you as soon as I have 15 rep! Thanks again!